# Exposing React App with Local MySQL Database to Internet Using Ngrok

Tags: mysql, reactjs, django, ngrok

I am very new to ngrok, so please bear with me.

I have a very simple React test app that is using Django as a server and local MySQL database. Django pulls/inserts some info from the local database and sends to the frontend. Everything works well.

What I'm trying to do is expose this local app to public Internet. I have successfully installed and configured Ngrok, established a tunnel and was able to view the app on a different computer through the address generated by Ngrok. The problem is, I was able to see only the UI that is not related to the database. All data that React pulls from the local database, was not visible when I used a different computer. My question is, is there a way to use the same app through Ngrok and get the same data from the local MySQL database that I see when I just run the app locally? I know that I can create another tunnel that exposes the port MySQL or Django are running on (3306 and 8000 respectively) but if I do this, how would I access the data through Ngrok? Would I need to change anything in React code?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to add some more details, especially browser console errors and code snippets related to the problem. But a guess from my end is that you've hardcoded the absolute URL instead of using a relative URL when talking with Django in your front-end. Instead of using `http://localhost:8000/some/route` you should use `/some/route` with whatever HTTP request library you use. The library/browser will ensure it calls the same host as what's currently in the address bar (the ngrok url or localhost).

Comment: Thank you. Am I right in thinking that if your app is using a server to fetch and send data to/from local database and is running on a different port, then I will need 2 separate ngrok tunnels (one for UI and the second for server)?